# Second scroll function not working? (Using ternary operators as flag)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Any idea why this isnt working? I have two scroll functions but it doesnt work. I tried combining them but that didnt really do the job either. Im wondering if the first scroll is interfering with the second scroll and why is that?

Love to learn the cause and if someone will answer with a solution it would be great if you comment the code so that I can learn from it.

**UPDATED CODE where I combined the two functions:**

```
var status = 0;
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var content_height = $(document).height()
    content_scroll_pos = $(window).scrollTop()
    percentage_value = content_scroll_pos * 100 / content_height
    newStatusA = percentage_value > 5 ? 2 : 1;
    newStatusB = percentage_value > 30 ? 2 : 1;

    if (newStatusA == status) return;
    switch (newStatusA) {
        case 1:
            TweenMax.to("#corner-menu", 2, {
                left: "-100%",
                ease: Power2.easeOut
            });
            break;
        case 2:
            TweenMax.to("#corner-menu", 2, {
                left: "0%",
                ease: Power2.easeOut
            });
            break;
    }

        if (newStatusB == status) return;
    switch (newStatusB) {
        case 1:
            TweenMax.to(".bar", 2, {
                right: "-125%",
                ease: Power2.easeOut
            })
            break;
        case 2:
            TweenMax.to(".bar", 2, {
                right: "0",
                ease: Power2.easeOut
            })
            break;
    }
    status = newStatusA;
    status = newStatusB;
});
```

**OLD CODE:**

```
    var status = 0;
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var content_height = $(document).height()
        content_scroll_pos = $(window).scrollTop()
        percentage_value = content_scroll_pos * 100 / content_height
        newStatusA = percentage_value > 5 ? 2 : 1;

        if (newStatusA == status) return;
        switch (newStatusA) {
            case 1:
                TweenMax.to(".corner-menu", 2, {
                    left: "-100%",
                    ease: Power2.easeOut
                });
                break;
            case 2:
                TweenMax.to(".corner-menu", 2, {
                    left: "0%",
                    ease: Power2.easeOut
                });
                break;
        }
        status = newStatusA;
    });

$(window).scroll(function () {
    var content_height = $(document).height()
    content_scroll_pos = $(window).scrollTop()
    percentage_value = content_scroll_pos * 100 / content_height
    newStatusB = percentage_value > 25 ? 2 : 1;

    if (newStatusB == status) return;
    switch (newStatusB) {
        case 1:
            TweenMax.to(".bar", 2, {
                right: "-125%",
                ease: Power2.easeOut
            })
            break;
        case 2:
            TweenMax.to(".bar", 2, {
                right: "0",
                ease: Power2.easeOut
            })
            break;
    }
    status = newStatusB;
});
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Two scroll handlers is a little pointless as it can all be done within the one.

Comment: FYI `newStatuB` typo of `newStatusB`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan well simply animating some divs on scroll. It works if I remove the second one but I need both functions. I actually did combine them by adding another newstatus variable to the first function and adding another if statement below the first with    status = newStatusB; below the first    status = newStatusA; but then I have the issue that when scrolling back up the second "if" uses newstatusA and not B

Comment: @AlexK. corrected. I will post a updated code on how I merged them

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan combined them but it just doesnt work because somehow when scrolling down 5 percent for corner-menu to show up wont make it disappear unless I scroll all way down until 30 percent then back up. The two if statements are somehow bount together now

Comment: @AlexK. combined the code

Comment: Two things. One, you're using the `status` variable before you've assigned it, with means because of js variable-hoisting means the in the comparison it will evaluate as `undefined` and the loose equality check you're using will only match `0`.  Two, it would be helpful if you rephrased your question as 'Expected behavior > actual behavior > relevant code' compared to 'Herez code. fix teh codez plz'.

Comment: @JaredSmith isnt the code self explanatory? also my comments explain the issue:  combined them but it just doesnt work because somehow when scrolling down 5 percent for corner-menu to show up wont make it disappear unless I scroll all way down until 30 percent then back up. The two if statements are somehow bount together now. So do you know what the culprit is?

Comment: http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html
and lest you think I'm being snobbish, I have broken most of the rules at one time or another and been appropriately burned :)
And no, I don't necessarily know why. You might set up a fiddle for people to test it.